# Readability and ERT's

Tags: lyx

I'm writing in Lyx and I'm using quite a lot ERTs (`TeX` boxes).

I was wondering if it possible to somehow close those boxes so I won't see them unless I click on them (but of course they are still there). It is hard to read all the information (outside of those ERT's).

Is there a way to achieve this in `LyX`? if not, could you suggest any tips on how to make it easier and cleaner?

Comment: Do as I did, write it in LaTeX directly

Comment: @vesii With your cursor inside an ERT, type "ctrl + i" to execute `inset-toggle`.